# Counting the number of linearly independent primitive elements of a field extension

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $L/K$ be a field extension with extension degree $n>1$. We say $L/K$ is simple if $L=K(a)$ for some a in $L$. In this case, $a$ is called a primitive element. My question is now about the dimension of the largest K-subspace of L whose nonzero elements are primitive, in the context of a finite extension of a finite field.

Comment: An element is not simple if and only if it lies in a proper sub-extension.  The sub-extensions are parameterised by the divisors of the degree of the extension.  Now do inclusion–exclusion.

Comment: It is true, but then how do you compute the dimension of the subspace generated by simple elements? In case $K$ is infinite, things work as one can use a well-known linear algebra theorem that asserts a vector space over an infinite field cannot be written as a union of its subspaces. We don't have such result for finite finite base field. See my manuscript about this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.05411.pdf

Comment: Ah, got it.  I was reading the question in the title, rather than the one in the body.  I agree that this is less obvious.

Comment: A related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333715/enumeration-of-field-generators-of-a-finite-field-over-mathbbf-q-which-a

Comment: Every finite extension of a finite field is simple, isn't it? If the degree $n$ is prime, then every element of $L$ that's not in $K$ is a simple element. It should be possible to write $L$ as a direct sum of $K$ and a vector space $V$ of dimension $n-1$ in this case, and all nonzero elements of $V$ will be simple.

Comment: Sure, every finite extension of a finite field is simple. The case that extension degree is prime is very special.

Comment: The standard terminology is that $a$ is then a *primitive* element.

Comment: Thanks, will edit it.

Comment: There still seem to be two different questions being asked— do you want $V\subseteq L$ such that every nonzero $a\in V$ is primitive, or just that every element of some basis for $V$ is primitive?

Comment: @Tim Campion I understand that these two problems are different but they are pretty related. What I want is to find the largest subspace $V$ whose every nonzero element is primitive.

Comment: Very nice question, Are you assuming the base field is finite ?